# How should I think of the uniform distribution on the sphere?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I was reading [these notes](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) and on page 49, without concern the author writes about $X$, a random vector on the Euclidean sphere in $\mathbf{R}^n$, 
that is spherically distributed. He even writes:
$$
X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\sqrt{n}S^{n-1}).
$$

The following question succeeds it:

> Show that the spherically distributed random vector
>   $X$ is isotropic. Argue that the coordinates of $X$
>   are not independent.

I realized I didn't understand what the distribution was exactly when I  tried to solve the problem. There is a footnote in the text which makes it seem like $\mathbf{P}(X^{-1}(A)) = \lambda(A)/\lambda(S^{n-1})$, where 
$\lambda$ is the $n-1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and $A$ is a borel subset. I this true? Also, is there an explicit way to see the claim in the question? It would suffice to show that $\mathbf{E}\langle X, x\rangle^2 = \|x\|^2$ for every vector $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$.

Comment: Given the first $n-1$ coordinates.  What can you say about the last one?

Comment: Well it is completely determined, because if $u \in S^{n-1}$, then $\|u\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i^2 + u_n^2 = 1$, so $u_n = \sqrt{1 - \sum_{1}^{n-1} u_i^2}$.

Comment: $X:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}^n$ so $X(\omega)$ has $n$ components.  Then ($n$) coordinates *aren't* independent (of each other).

Comment: Right. I understood this (though, thank you for giving a clear way to see it). I wanted to get help on the isotropy part, though. Any ideas @GNUSupporter?

Comment: Sorry to say no.  Let's wait for an answer.